# Is inputType="phone" limit the no of digits to take as inout

Tags: java, android

I used `android:inputType = "phone"` to take phone number as input, but if i give six digits it takes otherwise force close and fires the error that

> "NumberFormat exception not valid int value"

Actually i'm trying to convert that value to integer through:

```
phone = Integer.parseInt(phoneNumber.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phone number constist of around 10 digits how can you convert it to int. Just convert it to long.

Comment: phone number can also contain *,#-+ signs so converting to long is also not a good solution. You should keep it as string...

Answer (score 0):

You should know the range of integer in java

try to use Long...